# How to grap UITableHeaderView which was added via storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I added a UITableHeaderView via Storyboard - just drag and drop a view on top of the UITableView and add the @property to the class.h (Xcode 5) . I want to use that table header for progress information. Therefor I use

```
       self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
```

to hide the header when there is no progress going on.

When I want to show the tableHeaderView:

```
       self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.myHeaderView;
       [self.tableView reloadData]
```

But unfortunately the headerView wont show up.
What I am doing wrong?

Thank you for you help.

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution for my problem. 
I created a *.nib file for that view and added a function to my class

```
      - (void)showView{ ... }
```

I than init my view

```
     UIView *view[[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 50.0)];
```

and set my tableHeaderView

```
      self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Work's fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that setting the tableHeaderView Height to 0 works for me to get this same kind of functionality.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
yourSavedHeight = newFrame.size.height;
newFrame.size.height = 0;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = newFrame;
```

and then when you want it back

```
CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
yourSavedHeight = newFrame.size.height;
newFrame.size.height = yourSavedHeight;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = newFrame;
```

or you could combine the two above into one method with a BOOL parameter to either shrink it or grow it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found another solution for this problem. 
See my updated post above.